# View all copies of cached page on Google?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, google-search

I'm currently working on a project that deals with displaying cached versions of pages from Google.  However, it appears that they only show you the most recently cached page.

For example, I know I can use this:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com
```

But how can I view other cached copies of stackoverflow.com that Google cached years before?

Answer (score 1):

You may use **archive.org** service.

Example URL in your case will be `https://web.archive.org/web/*/stackoverflow.com`.
You will see calendar links with copies of your page.

If you want to see last copy, URL will be changed a little `https://web.archive.org/web/stackoverflow.com`.

For similar tasks I use https://cachearchive.com. You don't have to build long URL every time.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to web filters using cached pages, this might help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>View Text Only Cached Page</title>
<head>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function urlGen(f)
                        {
                            var i1 = "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:";
                            var i2 = f.intranet.value;
                            var i3 = "&hl=en&gl=ca&strip=1";

                            var fullURL = i1 + i2 + i3;
                            f.action = i1 + i2 + i3;

                            return i1 + i2 + i3;
                        }
                </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="row2">
                <!-- Intranet Search -->
                <form action="google.com" onSubmit="window.location.href=urlGen(this)" method="post" style="width:350px">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>View Text-only Cached Page</legend>
                <input type="text" id="intranet" size="45" value="insert link"
                    onFocus="this.value = ''"
                    onBlur="this.value = 'insert link'" / >

            <br>
<div style="width:300px;">
paste or type the address of the webpage you would like to view in a text only cached version and press "Enter".
<br/><br/>
<b>If a result is not found try adding "/" at the end of the submitted address.</b>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```